# Delphi saving to text file

Tags: delphi

Is there a way I can use coding
Memo1.lines.savetofile ('textfile1.txt') without it then deleting whatever already is in the texfile to save the memos lines?

Comment: Do you want to append your memo-data to the existing file, create a back-up of the existing file prior to saving your data or prompt the user that a file already exists and in that case continue/abort?

Answer (score 10):

Create a `TFileStream` that opens the existing file, seek to the end of the stream, and then pass the stream to `Memo1.Lines.SaveToStream()`.

Comment: It might be interesting to know that in terms of performance, this code is identical to `TFile.AppendAllText`. That's because `TMemoStrings.SaveToStream()` is actually `TStrings.SaveToStream()` which is based on `GetTextStr`. What's more, as written, this code will emit a BOM.

Comment: You can skip the BOM being output by providing a BOM-less `TEncoding` to `SaveToStream()`. For instance, if you want UTF-8, you can use `TEncoding.GetEncoding(65001)` in XE and earlier, or derive from `TUTF8Encoding` and override `GetPreamble()` in XE2 and later. `TMBCSEncoding` (which `GetEncoding()` returns) did not output a BOM until XE2.

Comment: Actually it's simplest to use the TStrings property, named WriteBOM or similar. You didn't address performance though. You left a comment on the other answer stating that it had a performance issue. But the code in this answer has the same performance issue. It seems only fair that you address that.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you want to append the text to the file. Do that like so:

```
TFile.AppendAllText(FileName, Memo1.Text);
```

This uses the [`TFile`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TFile) class from the `IOUtils` unit. Pass an encoding parameter if you want to exercise control over the encoding used.

Comment: The downside to this is that the entire Memo content has to be stored into a temporary String in memory before the file is then touched. And that String has to be converted to whatever encoding is used for the file. That can waste a lot of memory (albeit temporarily) and run slowly if the Memo has a lot of text in it.  So just be careful of that.

Comment: @remy I'd expect the performance of this to be good. Better than line by line processing because the Windows messages involved are a little expensive. But there would be a memory cost for sure. I doubt that speed would be an issue. And encoding needs to be handled no matter what. The advantage of this code is that it is a simple one-liner and so very readable and concise.